# how can i publish the artifact to the two or more repositories at the same time?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

how can i set the gradle script so that  i can publish the artifact to the two or more repositories at the same time?(not only the local repositories,may be all online repositories.)

```
   uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

            repository(url: sonatypeRepositoryUrl) {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }

            repository(url: githubRepositoryUrl)
        }
    }
```

Comment: how did you solve the issue ?